# Inequality of finite sequences of real numbers .

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Is the following inequality true for real numbers $\lambda_{i}$ and $\mu_{i}$

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\mu_{i}^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}}\times \dfrac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_{i}^{2}} \leq 1$$

I want to say that this is true but I can't seem to prove it kinda looks like some kind of inner product is going on, has anyone see this or an inequality like it before?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the $\lambda_i$? Because it’s certainly true if they’re positive.

Comment: No they can be negative, but they are bounded from below by a constant $-C$.

Comment: If $\lambda_i$ can be negative, for that to hold you will need to specify additional conditions.  otherwise note for e.g.: $$ \frac{-1\times 1+2\times4}{-1+2}\cdot\frac1{1+(1+4)} = \frac76 > 1$$  As scaling the $\lambda_i$ doesn't change anything, having just a lower bound won't help.